# ошибка при подключении к mysql в intellig idea

Tags: mysql, база-данных, intellij-idea

При создании соединения к базе данных mysql через idea получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пароль и логин вроде верный, подскажите пожалуйста в чём дело
Пытался указать конкретную версию в Specify Version, но это ни к чему не привело

Версия idea
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)

Версия mysq
mysql  Ver 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Comment: что значит вроде? для успеха вам нужен хост-порт-логин-пароль. Если сервер развернут локально, убедитесь что он запущен. Проверьте подключение через командую строку mysql, используете аналогичные настройки при подключении в приложении

Comment: sudo systemctl status mysql.service показывает статус running
заходит в консоль mysql, показывает базы данных, я посмотрю, может быть дело в драйвере.
спасибо